# When a process has run, but during the process the file gets deleted, how do i stop the error?

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I have created a inform which deletes old files. Firstly the form identifies all the folder then you have an option to delete it.

However, during testing i found that after identification, i deleted a file then clicked the delete button which resulted in the form to blow up.

does anyone know the solution to this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Learn how to handle exceptions gracefully in your application.  It involves using `try`...`catch` in your code.

Comment: Can you show your code, please?  We'll need more information on what you mean by your form "blows up".

Comment: You need to learn how to use try-catch

Comment: I assume it looks like this: https://chivethebrigade.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/lead-500-0.jpg

Comment: The error is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not find file 'c:\Nexdox\nxabd02\input\Aberdeen Literature requests - Aberweb 07.10.2015.xlsx.x'.

Comment: try
        {
          File.Delete(file);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
          UnDeletableFiles.Add(file);
          string error = string.Format("File cannot be deleted, it is currently open : {0}", file);
          WriteLogMessage(LogFileName, "");
          WriteLogMessage(LogFileName, error);
        }

Comment: i added a try catch already

Comment: Please,edit your question and add there (not in comments) all your relevant code

Comment: "i deleted a file then clicked the delete button which resulted in the form to blow up." Why do you click on the delete button after you already deleted it?

Comment: Anyway, the easy answer is to check if file exists before trying to delete it, using [File.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can almost never assume a file can be deleted without handling an exception. Even a File.Exists is not good enough. Another user or process can delete it in between the calls.

```
if (File.Exists(file))
{
    try
    {
        File.Delete(file);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

You can do nothing in the exception, log something, show a friendly message, or whatever is appropriate for your application.